Ambiguos pointer address change in rust while doing casting on Rc<RefCell<>>
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    pub data: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>,
}

fn main() {
    let x: u64 = 0x300007f50;
    let x_addr: u64 = &x as *const u64 as u64;
    unsafe {
        #[allow(invalid_reference_casting)]
        let x = &mut *(x_addr as *mut Foo);
        println!("{:?}", x.data.as_ptr());
    }
}


The output of this program is : 0x300007f68
I tried doing casting a virtual memory address to a Rc<RefCell<>> type.
I expected the program to return the same x as the pointer, but instead I got some offset value.
I wanted to know why and how is this happening?

The pointer within an Rc doesn't point directly at the T it owns; there is other metadata that an Rc keeps track of.

Also note that the output of this program is technically meaningless, because the line let x = &mut *(x_addr as *mut Foo); causes undefined behavior. It can therefore do anything, including completely nonsensical things.

Could you please clarify the intent behind your snippet, as it's not obvious, at least to me? The code takes the address of a u64, and cast it to a pointer to Foo, which contains an Rc<RefCell<&[u8]>> (a type which doesn't make much sense either because it keeps a reference behind a smart pointer), and then writes the address of its data member. Even in a world with no UB, where the compiler just generated code that did exactly what you wrote, what did you expect this to do?

Assuming what you want is actually valid, you should use Rc::from_raw instead of pointer casting, which will also make your example behave as you want.

@trueequalsfalse That will still cause UB in this sample.
